# Prove inversion formula involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, mobius-inversion

Let's say that we have such an equation:

$$f_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k}{k \choose i}g_i$$

Prove that in that case we can express $g_k$ like this:

$$g_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-i}{k \choose i}f_i$$

In order to prove that, count how many $f$'s and $g$'s there are on the right and on the left.

Comment: I have replaced "counting $f$ and $g$ on both sides of the equation" which was uninformative by "involving binomial coefficients" which is at least a little more precise. I was tempted to write "involving binomial transform" (see my comment to the answer of Brian M. Scott).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically just an exercise in manipulating binomial coefficients and summations.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}if_i&=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}i\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}jg_j\\
&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=j}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}i\binom{i}jg_j\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=j}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}j\binom{k-j}{k-i}g_j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}jg_j\sum_{i=0}^{k-j}(-1)^i\binom{k-j}i\,.
\end{align*}$$

Step $(1)$ is just reversing the order of summation, and $(2)$ is applying a standard binomial coefficient identity: $\binom{k}i\binom{i}j$ and $\binom{k}j\binom{k-j}{k-i}$ are both the number of ways to split $k$ things into three sets of cardinalities $j$, $i-j$, and $k-i$.

Now by the binomial theorem

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-j}(-1)^i\binom{k-j}i=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }k=j\\
0,&\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

since $\binom00=1$, so

$$\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}if_i=\binom{k}kg_k=g_k\,,$$

as desired.

Comment: for the OP : Transformation $(g_k) \to (f_k)$ has a name that deserves to be given for further investigations: [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform).

Answer (score 2):

The computations given by Brian M. Scott are the rigorous way of doing things.

Let me bring a supplementary light by a **linear algebra** explanation.

Consider the matrices associated resp. with the first and second (infinite) set of equations As infinite matrices aren't easy to deal with, let us consider that we are in a process where these infinite matrices are replaced by increasing size $n \times n$ submatrices extracted from them (like russian dolls). For example, when $n=5$ we would have:

$$P_5=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}1&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0\\1&2&1&0&0\\1&3&3&1&0\\1&4&6&4&1\end{array}\right) \ \ \text{with} \ \ F = P_5 G$$

where $F$, resp. $G$ is the column vector of $f_k$s, resp. $g_k$s.

$$Q_5=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}1&0&0&0&0\\-1&1&0&0&0\\1&-2&1&0&0\\-1&3&-3&1&0\\1&-4&6&-4&1\end{array}\right) \ \ \text{with} \ \ G = Q_5 F$$

The first one is the so-called "Pascal matrix" ; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) where you will see mentionned its inverse... which is $Q_5$.  What we have done for index $n=5$ is in fact valid for any $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the transformation $T_{\lambda}$ on sequences defined by

$$T_{\lambda} \colon (a_n)_n \mapsto  (b_n)_n$$

with
$$b_n = \sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{n}{i} \lambda^{n-i} a_i$$

Notice that $T_{\lambda}$ maps the sequence $(\alpha^n)$ to the sequence $((\alpha + \lambda)^n)$. We conclude that

$$T_{\lambda} \circ T_{\mu} = T_{\lambda + \mu}$$

Note also that $T_0 = \operatorname{Id}$, so $T_{-\lambda} = T_{\lambda}^{-1}$.

Let's now examine the behavior of generating functions and exponential generating functions under the transformation $T_{\lambda}$.

The sequence $(\alpha^n)$ has the generating function
$$f_{\alpha}(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}  \alpha^n x^n= \frac{1}{1-\alpha x}$$

Now notice that

$$\frac{1}{1- \lambda x} f_{\alpha}\left(\frac{x}{1- \lambda x}\right) = \frac{1}{1-(\alpha + \lambda) x}= f_{\alpha + \lambda}(x)$$

Therefore, at the level of generating functions, the transformation $T_{\lambda}$ has the form
$$f(x) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-\lambda x} f\left( \frac{x}{1-\lambda x}\right)$$

Now let's consider exponential generating functions. The sequence $(\alpha^n)$ has
$$F(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{ \alpha^n}{n!} x^n = \exp (\alpha x)$$
Therefore, at the level of exponential geneerating functions the maps $T_{\lambda}$ acts as

$$F(x) \mapsto \exp(\lambda x) \cdot F(x)$$